# CALayer draws differently with different screen sizes

Tags: ios, calayer

In my app, I'm drawing a circle around the centre of a label, but when I run it in the simulator, I have to make sure that the phone size I'm using in the storyboard file is the same as the simulated phone. Eg, if I have the storyboard phone as iPhone X, but run the simulator as iPhone 8 Plus, then this is what I get.

[image]

So I suppose this is because when it calculates the screen width and height, it looks at the storyboard file, and so it thinks that the label's centre is in a different place from where I want it to be. This also occurs when I run the app on a real iPhone.

Is this a problem when the app goes on the App Store? And if so, how should I fix it?

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: You are use roundCorner & set width you require

Comment: Could you please explain that a bit more?

Comment: give me storyboard file?

Comment: Well, I want to use CALayer as I have animations and pulsating effects that go with it. My main issue is that the screen width the CALayer uses is from the storyboard file and not the actual phone screen width.

Comment: you are try below method:
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) { }

Comment: That did not seem to fix it. The issue seems to be that it simply takes the storyboard's width and not the phones actual width. I don't mind if this is only a problem in the simulator but